# What does the expression "to stick the finger high in the air" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the expression "to stick the finger high in the air" mean? It is used in the text about politics.

Comment: Could you indicate a source?

Answer (score 4):

One puts one's finger in the air to check the wind direction. When used metaphorically in politics, "wind" is the prevailing opinion; putting one's finger "high in the wind" in this context means finding the position which is most likely to get one re/elected.

Answer (score 1):

"Sticking a finger in the air" also means to take a guess. When you add "high in the air" I assume that means taking a wild guess.
[Previously Discussed here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4562/whats-the-meaning-of-get-ones-finger-in-the-air)